# Does my OS will support these tools?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2008, asp.net

I am currently using Windows Server 2003 and I want to install Windows XP [SP1 or SP2 or SP3] or may be VISTA.

I have may application which I can run on Windows Server 2003 and I am curious to know If I could run the same on XP or Vista. Please help me deciding whether I change my OS or not, here is the List of software and app I want to work on:

1. Visual Studio 2008/2010
2. SQL Server 2008
3. ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework
4. WPF application

P.S. : I can create all my application [except WPF] with Windows Server 2003.

I have a idea that I can install VS 2008 on XP but not exactly sure about MVC framework and other latest technology stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with Windows XP? Just install Vista or Windows 7.

Any tool that works on Windows Server 2003 will, of course, work on later operating systems.

Comment: Hi John,
I am getting confidence with this statement
I have read somewhere that some people are getting issue while installing MVC in windows 7. , please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Everything you mentioned works on all three operating systems.  I've personally run them on XP and Win7.  The version of IIS in WinXP is very old and you have to do a little extra work to get MVC to behave the same as later versions, though.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest limitation that XP will give you is that it will only let you run one website in IIS at a time which is a problem if you are building web services. In addition, XP runs IIS 5.1 whereas Win2k3 runs IIS 6 and Vista runs IIS 7 and Windows 7 runs IIS 7.5 I believe. If given a choice to move to another OS and you are doing web development, I would go to Vista or Windows 7. MVC and WPF will install and run on both Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using all those tools in XP/VISTA/7 since a lot of time. There should be no issues.

And if the questions is if your apps created using those tools will run on XP/Vista, they should do perfectly. All you have to consider is the version of IIS.

Be aware that, if you don't want to install the asp.net MVC package, you still can run those apps on IIS, just be sure you set up the System.Web.MVC reference to copy always or local copy.